# Meaning of «Не читайте до обеда советских газет»

Tags: значения

I've been seeing the phrase *«Не читайте до обеда советских газет»* used in various contexts related to politics, mass media and biased information sources, but I don't really understand what it means. Here are some of my theories about its meaning:

- Newspapers in general can spoil appetite, so it's better to read after the first meal of the day;
- Morning newspapers contain bogus information, so it's better to wait until the afternoon issues;
- Soviet newspapers in particular induce desperation on its readers, so they're better avoided.

Are my theories correct, and what is the true meaning of this phrase?

Comment: To add to already existing answers, in modern usage - since  soviet newspapers no longer exist - this phrase just sarcastically points out the bad  quality of mass-media.

Comment: This is basically a question about what Bulgakov meant, not about language.

Answer (score 7):

This is a citation from **Собачье сердце** book by **Михаил Булгаков**:

> **Преображенский:** Если вы заботитесь о своем пищеварении, мой добрый совет — не говорите за обедом о большевизме и о медицине. И — боже вас сохрани — не читайте до обеда советских газет.
>   **Борменталь:** Гм… Да ведь других нет.
>   **Преображенский:** Вот никаких и не читайте. Вы знаете, я произвел 30 наблюдений у себя в клинике. И что же вы думаете? Пациенты, не читающие газет, чувствуют себя превосходно. Те же, которых я специально заставлял читать «Правду», — теряли в весе. […] Мало этого. Пониженные коленные рефлексы, скверный аппетит, угнетенное состояние духа.

So, your first assumption is backed by prof. Преображенский: Newspapers in general can spoil appetite.

As for the Soviet part of the phrase - the Борменталь's notes that there are no other newspapers available - only Soviet ones. So, here we can see an irony of the author - are the newspapers bad because they are Soviet, or all the newspapers are bad?

Comment: I think that Bulgakov specifically meant Soviet newspapers, especially because bolsheviks closed all other media. However, the popularity of this phrase today is due to the fact that it is perceived to be so applicable to the state of the contemporary media in Russia

Comment: I am certain that word Soviet is there for a purpose. "Pravda" is also one of the most famous Soviet newspapers. So, Борменталь's comment is pseudo-excuse and by adding it Bulgakov makes sure that nobody misses the point here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quote from Bulgakov's [Heart of a Dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_a_Dog) novel widely used in russian language and points to a bad side of soviet propaganda.

The full quote definitely will help you to understand it:

> - Food, Ivan Arnoldovich, is a subtle thing. One must know how to eat, yet just think – most people don’t know how to eat at all. One must not only know what to eat, but when and how.
>
> (Philip Philipovich waved his fork meaningfully.)
>
> -And what to say while you’re eating. Yes, my dear sir. If you care about your digestion, my advice is – don’t talk about bolshevism or medicine at table. **And, God forbid – never read Soviet newspapers before dinner.**’
>
> - **M’mm . . . But there are no other newspapers.**
>
> - **In that case don’t read any at all.** Do you know I once made thirty tests in my clinic. And what do you think? The patients who never read newspapers felt excellent. Those whom I specially made read Pravda all lost weight.”

Answer (score 1):

The author of the question about that phrase almost found out the real meaning in his theory #3: "Soviet newspapers in particular induce desperation on its readers, so they're better avoided".

In the context of the story M. Bulgakov meant that most of soviet newspapers untill 1970-1980 were full of negative information, pretentious propaganda, latent western threat, "the image of the enemy", many others, and glorification of Bolshevism in general. It was nothing but totally brainwashing and permanent effort to influence on public perception. Even "positive" news had the real meaning to praice Bolshevism. For example: "Soviet combine driver Ivan Ivanov saved the life of the chipmunk while harvesting". What a gentleman!! What the nice Soviet ideology is!
Also some news had "positive" context but it was obvious that it could not make a person happy. For example: "The Soviet Children's chorus performed the concert in the friendly German Democratic Republic". Ok. So what? Who cares? Are you serious?

By the way in the context of the story, Professor Preobrajensky didn't like the "social revolution" and Bolshevism at all. So he was against reading that newspapers.